# Running a snakemake pipeline with different configs from same working directory

Tags: configuration, snakemake

Can a snakemake pipeline be run with two different configs from the same working directory?

Config files here would have a "project name" parameter that would define the input and output path for the pipeline. Since snakemake locks the working directory, I wonder if running the same pipeline with different config files in the same working directory would result in some conflict. If yes, is there any viable alternative strategy for this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can choose the config file using `$snakemake --configfile my_config_file`. You can run two instances of snakemake at the same time. Snakemake does not lock the directory itself. It has two types of locks, input and output locks. If there is no overlap between the files created by the two workflows, they can run simultaneously. If there is an overlap in the files the workflows will create, you should create these files first. Overlap in input files is not a problem. A workflow only releases it's locks after it completes/ is interrupted. It takes a bit of time for snakemake to set up the locks, so launching two instances at exactly the same time can sometimes cause problems.

Comment: Can snakemake raise a warning if there is a conflict in output files to be created? Or, it's on us to be careful about it?

Comment: Snakemakes keeps track of the locks (just a file with file names). The first instance will set output locks for all files the workflow will produce. Another instance will refuse to run if that workflow contains output files that are locked. I think the error message is "Directory is locked".

Comment: That's helpful. Thanks!